# Jenkins throw an error with Maven goal cargo

Tags: maven, jenkins

When using Jenkins to build our project it throws the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:redeploy (default-cli) on project xxxxx: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:redeploy failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat8x], type = [remote]], configuration type [runtime]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:redeploy (default-cli) on project xxxxxx: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.2.4:redeploy failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [tomcat8x], type = [remote]], configuration type [runtime]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it?
```

The plugin is declare as shown in the image below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIQUs.png)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use images when you can use indented code.